# Why does Mathematica have a separate StackExchange site and isn't a part of StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion

The quesion has been haunting me for a long time. *StackOverflow* is a general service for many different programming languages. *Mathematica* is just one among those programming languages. Why was the *Mathematica* subsite separated from *StackOverflow*?

What is happening?

Comment: Thank goodness it is out. The community of Mathematica StackExchange is much more helpful than the general StackOverflow community. But I think the reason is that Mathematica is more than a programming language - it is also curated mathematical and scientific packages of computer code and curated data.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This question was discussed a lot when the site was originally proposed.  In fact, the SE team even rejected the proposal at one point on the grounds that it overlapped SO too much.  However, a [great post](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3750) sums up the reason for the site's existence (and, along with community support, likely had much to do with the reversal of the rejection).